# Displaying MongoDB results in chartkick using ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, chartkick

I have this output from a query in MongoDB using Ruby :

```
irb(main):087:0>   data = col.find({}, :fields => ["result", "time"])
=> <Mongo::Cursor:0x14768b8 namespace='spark.light' @selector={} @cursor_id=>

irb(main):090:0> data.first
=> {"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('537d961197c20960ad000001'), "result"=>2177, "time"=>2014-05-22 06:15:45 UTC}
```

Now I want to give this data to chartkick running on Ruby on Rails to draw a linechart
.The input shall looks like this :

```
"2014-05-22 06:15:45 UTC" => "2177"
```

Is there any clean way to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would transform records into a hash of `time => result`:

```
Hash[data.map do |item|
  [item['time'], item['result']]
end]

# => { 2014-05-22 06:15:45 UTC => 2177, 2014-05-22 06:20:00 UTC => 1000 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Hash#values_at`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-i-values_at) with [`Hash::[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D) method :

```
Hash[data.first.values_at('time', 'result')]
```